# R : add number of observations on graph with fill and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Quite new with R and still struggling with graphs.

How to display the number of observations above all violin boxes in a facet_wrap graph that also differenciates a categorical variable by color ?

Here is an example with the R built-in data set "CO2" :

```
graph <- CO2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=uptake, fill=Type)) + geom_violin(width=1) +   facet_wrap(vars(Plant))
graph + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 50), position = "bottom", labels=scales::number) + labs(title= "CO2 dataset : Upate versus Treatment, Type and Plant", x="Treatment", y="Uptake") + scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```

[image: How to add number of observations on top of violin boxes ?]

There are solutions for simpler graphs (with facets but without colored fill) but I did not manage to adapt them to this graph configuration.

Thanks !

Comment: I think I know how, but could you provide some data so I can replicate?

Comment: That would be great. It is the R built-in data set "CO2" (you can copy/paste the code, it will work).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, using a helper data frame with the totals and passing `inherit.aes=FALSE` to `geom_text` so it doesn't need the other aesthetics. I'm not sure if I am showing the number you want, that is easy to change by modifying `totals`.

```
totals = CO2 %>% 
  count(Plant) %>% 
  mutate(label=paste('Count:', n), Treatment='nonchilled', uptake=50)
CO2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=uptake, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_violin(width=1) +   
  facet_wrap(vars(Plant)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 60), position = "bottom", labels=scales::number) + 
  labs(title= "CO2 dataset : Upate versus Treatment, Type and Plant", x="Treatment", y="Uptake") + 
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=totals, aes(Treatment, uptake, label=label), 
            vjust=0, hjust=0, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Actually it's almost what I would like. I'like to have a count label for both Type (Quebec and Mississipi); for the top left facet, this would lead to 7 on top of the red violin box and 0 on top of the empty space (replacing the "empty" blue violin box) and so on for every facet.

Comment: I adapted your answer and modify my code. It now works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Kent-Johnson proposal, here is a code that works.
[image: Now works well!]

```
totals_nonchilled <- CO2 %>% 
  group_by(Plant, Treatment, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  count(Plant) %>% tidyr::spread(key=Treatment, value=n) %>%
  mutate(label=paste(nonchilled), Treatment='nonchilled', uptake=45)

totals_chilled <- CO2 %>% 
  group_by(Plant, Treatment, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  count(Plant) %>% tidyr::spread(key=Treatment, value=n) %>%
  mutate(label=paste(chilled), Treatment='chilled', uptake=45)

totals <- dplyr::bind_rows(totals_nonchilled, totals_chilled)

graph <- CO2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=uptake, fill=Type)) +
  geom_violin(width=1) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Plant))

graph + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 50), position = "bottom", labels=scales::number) + labs(title= "CO2 dataset : Upate versus Treatment, Type and Plant", x="Treatment", y="Uptake") + scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=totals, aes(Treatment, uptake, label=label), 
            vjust=0, hjust=0, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Comment: You can simplify the calculation of `totals` to ```totals = CO2 %>% 
  count(Plant, Treatment, name='label') %>% 
  complete(Plant, Treatment, fill=list(label=0)) %>% 
  mutate(uptake=45)
```